# Como usar JSF e Spring Boot Starter JDBC no mesmo projeto?

Tags: java, aplicação-web, spring-boot

Vi um vídeo sobre o Spring Boot Starter JDBC e gostaria de utilizá-lo em uma aplicação web com JSF.

Alguém sabe se é possível e como proceder para fazer a configuração?

Comment: Carlos, bem-vindo ao [pt.so]! Essa é uma pergunta de complexidade relativamente alta. Seria interessante se você mostrasse uma configuração básica do seu projeto atual, pois podem haver formas diferentes de "casar" as duas tecnologias. Abraço!